# Authenticated Users Viewable pages

Tags: php

I have set up my site so when a user is logged in, a log out button appears which I want on every page if the user is logged in. I have used sessions to do this and if a user tries to access a page it will redirect them to the log in page. I have included the session script on the about us page but if the user is not logged in then it cannot be viewed. I want anybody to be able to browse the about page whether they are logged in or not. If I take the script out of the about us page then the logged in user will not have the option to log out if they are viewing the about us page.

This is the session

```
 session_start();

// Check if we have established an authenticated
if (!isset($_SESSION["authenticatedUser"]))
{
 $_SESSION["message"] = "Please Login";
  header("Location: About_Us.php");
}
else
 { ?>
```

This is the Log in/out button change

```
<div class="Login">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["authenticatedUser"] ?></a></li>
<?php   
if(isset($_SESSION['authenticatedUser'])) {
    echo '<li><a href="logout.php"><span>Log Out</span></a></li>';
} else {
    echo '<li><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li>';
} 
?> 
  <li><a href="Register.php">Register</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Basket</a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!--Login-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php session_start();?>
<div class="Login">
<ul>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['authenticatedUser']) && $_SESSION['authenticatedUser'] != null ) {?>
  <li><a href="#">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["authenticatedUser"] ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="logout.php"><span>Log Out</span></a></li>
<?php } else {?>
  <li><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li>
<?php } ?> 
  <li><a href="About_up.php">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="Register.php">Register</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Basket</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The above code will show logout button to a logged in user and logIn button to a normal user

Comment: Your a genius!! Thanks for your help got it all sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your redirect block as:

```
// Check if we have established an authenticated
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != 'About_Us.php' && !isset($_SESSION["authenticatedUser"]))
{
  $_SESSION["message"] = "Please Login";
  header("Location: About_Us.php");
  exit;
}
// no need for else
```

This will redirect users if they are not authenticated & current page is not aboutus page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I seem to be getting a redirect loop now.

Comment: If your about us page is not on main path, you need to specify full path like: `if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/foo/bar/About_Us.php'`